# zipWith function in Scala

Tags: functional-programming, scala

My implementation works, but it looks very ugly. Curious to see how it's better implemented.

The `zipWith` function takes a list of lists (`List[List[A]]`), or a row with columns if you like. It will then transform this into a column with rows and applies a function `List[A]=>B` to obtain a `List[B]`. Hopefully the unit test below explains this better.

```
  test("zipWith"){
    val input = List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9))
    val expected = List("1::4::7", "2::5::8", "3::6::9")
    assert(zipWith(input)(_.mkString("::")) === expected)
  }
```

and the implementation is:

```
  def zipWith[A, B](lists: List[List[A]])(f: List[A] => B): List[B] = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(acc: List[B], input: List[List[A]]): List[B] = {
      val init = (Nil: List[List[A]], Nil: List[A])
      val (left, zipped) = input.foldLeft(init)((z, a) => {
        val (tails, heads) = z
        (a.tail :: tails, a.head :: heads)
      })
      if (left.foldLeft(false)(_ || _.isEmpty))
        f(zipped.reverse) :: acc
      else
        loop(f(zipped.reverse) :: acc, left.reverse)
    }

    loop(Nil, lists).reverse
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain us more about what you are exactly trying to accomplish with your code? Please edit it into the question.

Comment: @skiwi: Added some explanation. Hopefully the test will make it clear..

Comment: You do realize that the code can be replaced with this and will achieve the same thing: `def zipWith[A, B](lists: List[List[A]])(f: List[A] => B): List[B] = lists.map(f)`?
Are you looking at improving your style?

Comment: @AkosKrivachy post an answer with that!

Comment: @AkosKrivachy: No that will result in List(1::2::3, 4::5::6, 7::8::9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
def zipWith[A, B](ts: Traversable[Traversable[A]])(f: Traversable[A] => B): Traversable[B] = {
  ts.transpose.map(f)
}
```

Example:

```
scala> zipWith(input)(_.mkString("::"))
res10: Traversable[String] = List(1::4::7, 2::5::8, 3::6::9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Your variable names could be better, I would rather use rows and columns as a reader can understand it easier.
- `List` is an implementation of `Seq`, you should probably use `Seq` where you can.

With that said I would do something like this:

```
def zipWith[A, B](lists: Seq[Seq[A]])(f: Seq[A] => B): Seq[B] = {
  lists.headOption.map(_.size) match {
    case None =>
      // Input list is empty, return empty
      Seq.empty[B]
    case Some(columnCount) =>
      // Do a sanity check, based on column length of first row.
      require(lists.forall(_.size == columnCount), "Can't zip rows that have differing column lengths.")
      val initial = Seq.fill(columnCount)(Seq.empty[A])
      val zippedByColumns = lists.foldLeft(initial) {
        case (columns, nextRow) =>
          columns.zip(nextRow).map{ case (column, rowElement) => column :+ rowElement }
      }
      zippedByColumns.map(f)
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope that will result in List(1::2::3, 4::5::6, 7::8::9). It needs to be List("1::4::7", "2::5::8", "3::6::9")

Comment: @BasilTomato Thank you for pointing that out. Updated my answer with an actual solution.

Comment: I've seen it stated that one should prefer Vector to List as a concrete instantiation of Seq (but obviously use Seq as arguments where possible) as Vector ends up being better at things List should be better at anyways

Comment: Why not match on the headOption and then use the .size on the Some?